# C# Is List contained in Another list?

Tags: c#, contains

I have this set:

```
List<short> delegatingUserRoles = await (from urols in _dbContext.UsersRoles
                                                        join u in _dbContext.Users on urols.UserId equals u.UserId
                                                        where (u.Username == delegation.UserDelegating)
                                                        select urols.RoleId).Distinct().ToListAsync();
            
            if (delegatingUserRoles.ConvertAll(i => (int)i).All(item => (delegation.UserSelectedRoles).Contains(item))){
                //true
            }
```

delegation.UserSelectedRoles is a list of int, subset of delegatingUserRoles

example delegatingUserRoles has values 1,2,3,4 while
delegation.UserSelectedRoles has values 1,2,3

Why it does not enter the if?

Comment: Can you provide the real code? That code doesn't compile if `delegatingUserRoles` and `UserSelectedRoles` are `List<T>` because a `List<T>` is not `T`. Maybe you use an `ArrayList` ort `List<Object>`, but then you should really show us your code.

Comment: Unless `delegatingUserRoles` is a `List<object>`, that code won't return anything because it won't even compile

Comment: Are you only interested in a set-wise comparison? What would you expect the result to be if `delegatingUserRoles` was (say) {1, 1, 3, 2, 4} and `userSelectedRoles` was {1, 2, 3, 4}? The order is different *and* `delegatingUserRoles` has 1 twice. Note that if you want to treat these as sets, then it would be best to *create* sets... then you can use the existing methods for that.

Comment: Using the `Except()` method, you can remove elements that are common in both lists. After doing this, you can compare the number of elements in the original list and say contains if there is a difference.

    `bool contains=delegatingUserRoles.Except(UserSelectedRoles).Count() != list1.Count;
 Console.WriteLine(contains);`

Comment: You could use [`HashSet<T>.IsSubsetOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.issubsetof?view=net-7.0): `bool contained = UserSelectedRoles.ToHashSet().IsSubsetOf(delegatingUserRoles)`. But you should consider to use `HashSet<T>` in the first place(for both).

Comment: Maybe you wanna use a hashset for this?

Comment: { 1, 2, 3 } does not contain 4...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var l1 = new List<Int32> { 1 };
var l2 = new List<Int32> { 1,2,3 };

var r = l1.All(l => l2.Contains(l));
```

r = true

Answer (score 1):

That `Contains` method tests whether a specific item is contained in a list. It doesn't test whether a list of items are all contained in a list. You could do this:

```cs
if (UserSelectedRoles.All(item => delegatingUserRoles.Contains(item))
```

Comment: `O(n*n)` though

Comment: It's worth noting that that treats both collections as effectively sets - where the count of each item is irrelevant, as is the ordering. That may well be okay for the OP, but it's probably worth clarifying.

Comment: @CodeCaster, how long would the lists have to be for that to be worth worrying about? Longer than I suspect any list of user roles would ever be.

Comment: We write code for the general case, not the specific one. The next reader may have more than a handful of items in their lists. It never hurts to warn, and/or to explain what your code does.

Comment: @JonSkeet, fair point in general but, as this question is dealing with lists of user roles, unlikely to be relevant here.

Comment: @jmcilhinney: If the OP were likely to be the only person ever reading the answer, I'd agree. But as we know Stack Overflow answers are often read as the result of searches, I'd suggest clarifying the answer to note its assumptions/limitations.

Comment: see code updates

Answer (score 0):

Because the `Contains()` method checks if a single object is contained within the list, not if a list is contained within another list.

I think you need `All()` here.

Comment: But SequenceEqual doesn't check whether one list is contained within another list either. It checks whether the sequences are *equal*.

Comment: @JonSkeet You are right. All() is a right solution here.